# How to open a popup div in Codebehind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Open Popup on Item Template c#.
My problem is that when i click the popup it will open the popup but it will not hit the RowCommand argument(i.e. e.commandname).
Here is the code:

```
 <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="imgAppointment" Text="Appointment" runat="server" Style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" CommandName="App" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CssClass="label label-sm label-success" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddTask"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
```

This is the code on :

```
 protected void gvTaskDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
 if (e.CommandName == "App")
        {
            DataTable retval = obj.FetchAppointmentByMalmrktId(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            if (retval.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Repeater rptCustomers = (Repeater)Page.FindControl("rptCustomers");
                rptCustomers.DataSource = retval;
                rptCustomers.DataBind();

            }
        }
            }
```

This is the popup div:

```
  <div class="modal fade " id="AddTask" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: -15px !important;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-right: 0; width: 50%; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0px; background: #fff; height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h3 class="text-primary text-big" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><b>Appointment </b></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" id="btnAddTaskclose"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div class="box-model">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 140px;">Appointment Date :
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 140px;">Details  :
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 400px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbAppointmentdt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Appointmentdate") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 400px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>Status
                                    <br />
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Cancel Appointment</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>


                    </asp:Repeater>
```

ter>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trigger the event manually if nothing else works.
If the command event is what you need (if I correctly understand), you can hit the event like this:

```
<script >
    function myModalFunction() {
        $("#AddTask").modal();
    } </script>

// method to trigger an jsFunction
public void dispararJSfunction(string script)
{
    try
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.Page.GetType(), "its working", script, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Master.MostrarMsn(ex.Message, 0); }
}

protected void imgAppointment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // script = the js modal function
    dispararJSfunction("myModalFunction()");

    CommandEventArgs commandArgs = new CommandEventArgs("Command Name Here", "Your Command Argument Here");
    //You can pass any row
    //You can also skip the row parameter and get the row from Command Argument
    GridViewCommandEventArgs eventArgs = new GridViewCommandEventArgs(GridView1.Rows[0], GridView1, commandArgs);
    GridView1_RowCommand(GridView1, eventArgs);
}
```

If I'm missing something let me know. This is what it came up first to my head. I hope this can help you in some way.

Comment: Sir I Want to open the popup windows through gridview itmetemplate linkbutton..i am not understand..can you tell me details??

Comment: There is a gridview name gvTaskDetails..In this gridview a Itemtemplate having name Appointment ...when i click on Linkbutton of gvTaskDetails it will open a popup div having id AddTask ..To open this i am using data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddTask" ..In that div there is a repeater having id=rptCustomers ..I want to fetch value of that repeater by using gvTaskDetails_RowCommand ..The problem is that when i use  gvTaskDetails_RowCommand then it will not fire due to the use of data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddTask"..so how i use??